# PDFTRON doesn't release interop processes after success conversion

Tags: c#, ms-word, task, interop, pdftron

I made test sample:

```
PDFNet.Initialize();
pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.Install();
pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.SetMode(pdftron.PDF.Convert.Printer.Mode.e_interop_only);

string sourceDir = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Files";
string destDir = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\result_files";

var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir).AsEnumerable();
files = files.Concat(files).Concat(files).Concat(files).Concat(files);
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    tasks.Add(
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var doc = new PDFDoc())
                {                                   
                    pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToPdf(doc, file);
                    string resultPath = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".pdf");
                    doc.Save(resultPath, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_compatibility);
                    Console.WriteLine(file);
                }
            })
        );
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

I try to parallelize `Convert.ToPdf` calls. Also I have installed Office Pro 2016 on my machine and preferred conversion mode for me is `interop` mode. I have to say that I convert `doc/docx -> pdf`. What I found after success conversion some `winword.exe` still alive. I made few tests with 50 files and approximately 20 word processes were alive. I wonder what I did wrong here?

Comment: What version of PDFNet SDK are you running? Can you call PDFNet.GetVersion at runtime? Also, does the issue depend on the input files? What if you picked one file, and made 49 more copies of it and converted those?

Comment: @Ryan, thanks a lot for your time. Version is 6.10069952. Also, I updated question a bit, could you please check? I really did what you said. Could you please explain me why it's wrong, please? I also read about lock option, not sure I should use here.

Comment: The code looks fine. My hunch right now is that there are specific input files causing Word to stay around. Can you reproduce with 50 copies of just one file? What about other files?

Comment: @Ryan, the problem I can't replicate each time. I received this maybe 2/20. Maybe OS problems if you said code is fine. I will make stable test on server and will let you know. I understand the problem may sounds strange for you I just worried about how it will work in production. Another thing I wanna ask if you could share some implementation details. You don't any threads restrictions right? I mean bandwidth only depends on OS configuration?

Comment: Interesting that it is not 100% of the time with the same set of files. Testing on a different computer would definitely be a good idea. As for implementation details, on our end the interop supports full multi-threading, no restrictions.

Comment: @Ryan thanks a lot again.